# Parquet schema management

Tags: hadoop, version-control, parquet, data-migration

I have recently started working on a new project where we use Spark to write/read data in Parquet format. The project is changing rapidly and here and there we do need to change the schema of parquet files regularly. I am currently struggling with versioning data and code.

We use versioning system for our codebase but its very hard (at least in my opinion) to do it for data itself. I also have migration script, which I use to migrate data from old schema to the new schema but along the way I loose the information about what was the schema of a parquet file before running the migration. It is my priority to know the original schema as well.

So my questions would be

- How do you keep track of parquet files which have schema inconsistencies in your HDFS? I have several Terabytes of parquet files.
- After running migration script to convert your current schema(original) to the new schema, how do you keep track of original schema?
- Is there any existing tool to achieve this or I have to write something of my own?

Answer (score 2):

You can use[delta lake](https://delta.io/)  it has feature of overwriting schema and maintaining previous
versions of data

delta lake is basically a bunch of parquet files with a delta log(commit log)

```
data.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/delta-table")
```

The above code snippet overwrites normal parquet file which means that previous data will be overwritten

```
data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/delta-table")
```

The above is delta lake overwrite it go and check the delta log and overwrite a new version of data in the delta lake as version 1 with time stamp(if previous data was version zero)
we can also time travel(read previous versions of data) in delta lake

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf", 0).load("/tmp/delta-table")
```

this code can be used read zeroth version of the data